# Using to_char to convert number or date with xmltable

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmltable, to-char

I have this query like this:

```
select to_number(column_value) as IDs from xmltable('1,2,3,4,12.33,testtest');
```

Is it possible to use to_char function to convert numbers and strings inside xmltable to rows? So my output would be like this:

| output |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 12,33 |
| testtest |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current list of values you'll get:

```
select to_number(column_value) as IDs from xmltable('1,2,3,4,12.33,testtest');
```

```
ORA-19228: XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix '.', local-name ''
```

It would work with just numeric values:

```
select to_number(column_value) as IDs from xmltable('1,2,3,4,12.33');
```

| IDS |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 12.33 |

And it would work if the string value looked like an identifier, i.e. if you were able to enclose it in double quotes within your value list:

```
select to_number(column_value) as IDs from xmltable('1,2,3,4,12.33,"testtest"');
```

```
ORA-01722: unable to convert string value containing 't' to a number:
```

... except of course you can't convert the string 'testtest' to a number.

But you can treat them all as strings instead:

```
select column_value as IDs from xmltable('1,2,3,4,12.33,"testtest"');
```

| IDS |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 12.33 |
| testtest |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_fRDy_55)

If you're working with a list of values you're being passed then adding the double quotes around strings is feasible but probably not worth the effort, and a normal hierarchical query or recursive CTE approach to splitting the CSV list into values is likely to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about xmltable. But, if you can extract the string, you can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` AND `LEVEL`. Here is the [sample code](https://dbfiddle.uk/v0FP15Q_):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,2,3,4,12.33,testtest', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS IDs
FROM dual
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,2,3,4,12.33,testtest', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL;
```

Here is sample output:

[image]

Comment: I tried using `clob` instead of `varchar` in the string `regexp_substr` to have a limited range of possibilities, but it returns blank lines. Is there a way to eliminate blank lines?